# Cons of installing OS on external drive

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I want to install a linux distro (Arch) to dual boot with, but I'm wondering what the cons are of installing it on an external drive (that has USB 3). I've installed another linux distro on the external drive but that is for a niche purpose, not something I will use regularly (therefore don't have to worry about performance).

The Arch I will be installing will be my main distro of choice, so I am wondering if there will be any speed hindering if I choose to install it on an external drive. The main reason I want to install it on the external is so I can take it with me need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I routinely have used external disks and USB sticks for Linux distros, with only USB 2, with no issues, though my apps are not disk I/O intensive. USB 1 was not too usable, although I used to try to run an old Red Hat version with a parallel port ZIP drive (if any still remember those :-)

USB 3 should not have problems at all, as the speed limit exceeds that of most disk transfers I think.